Constructing Embedding Diagram of Reissner-Nordstrom Dihole
Is it possible to create embedding diagrams of $\phi=constant$ slices of axisymmetric two black home spacetimes, like the Reissner-Nordstrom dihole?
$d\Sigma^2=U(x,y)^2(dx^2+dy^2)$
I ask because the two variable dependency seems to make the process not as straightforward as in for example the Schwarzschild case. Also there’s the question: if I’m numerically integrating, do I start from the center of each hole and integrate outwards?

Could you write the line element in full?

Yes, $U(x,y)=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt((x-1)^2+y^2)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt((x+1)^2+y^2)}$. Normally, in cylindrical coordinates, you replace $y$ with $p$ and $x-1$and $x+1$ with $z-1$ and $z+1$. Then the metric looks like $ds^2=-\frac{dt^2}{U(p,z)^2}+U(p,z)^2(dp^2+dz^2+ p^2d\phi^2)$.

When you're asked for more info in a question, you are supposed to edit the question itself to add it.   Comments are not guaranteed to be persistent (can be deleted) and people should not be expected to scan comments for important information.

“if I’m numerically integrating, do I start from the center of each hole and integrate outwards?” - Black holes are 4-dimensional spacetimes that don’t have a “center”. The “center” of the Reissner-Nordstrom black hole is an infinitely long straight line representing the worldline of the timelike point singularity. I am not an expert on numerical gravity, but logically physical equations describe the evolution of the system from the cause represented by the boundary condition to the result represented in this case by the singularities where causal geodesics end.

I don’t think there is an exact solution for the Reissner-Nordstrom “dihole”. So it is unclear what you intend to integrate, the Reissner-Nordstrom metric, which is not the metric of the “dihole”, or the gravitational equations, for which you may not have enough computing power. It also is unclear what type of embedding you are asking for, as normally black holes cannot be isometrically embedded into “plus one” dimensional flat spacetime. Voting to close as lacking clarity.
